# How to have a different Elastic Spring Data index per request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a SpringMvc @RestController with an indexing function.

I want a different index to be used according to the request. For example if the request parameter is "en" then the index to be used will be that. I am trying to make a multilingual index with a different analyzer per language.

As far as I have seen , I need to annotate (I am only using Java Config) my POJO with

*@Document(index="en")*

but how do I manage that real-time?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1. ES Java client API.**

You need to do it manually with `ElasticsearchClient` (ES Java client API).  The `ElasticsearchRepository` and `ElasticsearchTemplate` do not support this.

**Option 2. SpEL in the index name.**

You can use SpEL in the index name, but you have to create indices per language yourself (e.g. on application start).

```
@Document(index="mydoc-#{@myLocaleService.currentLocale}")
@Settings("myindex-settings.json")
public class MyDoc {
  String id;
  Locale locale;
  String content;
}

@Service
MyLocaleService {
  public Locale getCurrentLocale() { return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(); }
}

interface MyDocRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyDoc, String>() {
}

@Service
MyDocService {

  @Autowired MyDocRepository repository;

  public void saveToIndex(MyDoc entity){
    try { 
       LocaleContext savedLocaleCtx = LocaleContextHolder.getLocaleContext();
       LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(entity.getLocale());
       myDocRepo.save(entity);
    } finally {
       LocaleContextHolder.setLocaleContext(savedLocaleCtx);
    }
  }
}
```

**Hint:** Use [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to reuse index settings per language.

**Option 3. Custom ES template.**

Alternatively, implement a custom `ElasticsearchOperations` that would identify and create indices per language for your entities dynamically. To identify the current locale either use a special property in the entity, or `LocaleContextHolder`.